# Some users unable to see files that others can see

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, filesystems, file-sharing

I have a file server running on Windows Server 2008 R2 in our domain that houses files created by an application and then moved to a folder available as a share to some users here.

Users who use this share will receive an email when new files have been moved to this folder (by the application that moves them). Some users are reporting that when they browse to that folder that either it is empty or that there are no new files.  I can go and look and see the new files but on their system even after a reboot they do not appear.  It is only affecting a few users, all running Windows 7 Professional.

Initially I thought it might be some sort of caching or offline files problem but I've verified that offline files is disabled on these users' PCs.  Permissions are also good and these users are local admins on their PCs.

Can anyone suggest why else this might be happening?

EDIT: A screenshot showing my system on the left and a user's system on the right, showing the discrepancy.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6xw0.jpg

Comment: I would start with checking that they really are trying to access the same folder on the same server and not something very similar. Then I would try to list files with some other file manager or with cmd in order to isolate possible windows explorer issue.

Comment: Access Based Enumeration. Users will only be able to see files to which they have permissions. To other users, the files will be invisible.

Comment: Agree with Ryan. It sounds like ABE, which is what I'd check first.

Comment: I have looked and Access-based Enumeration isn't enabled for this (or any) share.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's not Accessed Based Enumeration, the files could be invisible to users that don't have permission to access them.  The word "moved" in your first sentence jumped out at me.  I'm assuming that the application which creates the files is running either as domain administrator, or a service account.  Whatever files are created by that process will have limited permissions.  A **moved** file will retain it's ACL's.  However, if you **copy** the file, the copy is considered a new entity, and will take on the permissions of the parent folder where it is created.

First, check the permissions of the files in question to verify what they are.  Try logging onto one of the user's PC's as domain administrator and see if you can see the file that way.  Ultimately, I'm guessing you'll want to modify your process so that it copies the files rather than moving them.  You can then delete the source files if you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might have offline files enabled and the clients are viewing the folder's local offline cache.  I would test this by turning offline files off, rebooting (required), and then looking at the folders again.  If that is the cause, roll it out via GPO.

Comment: As mentioned previously, Offline files is not enabled.

Comment: Can they view the folders from a different machine?  In other words, can you isolate it to a user issue, or a computer issue?

Comment: I haven't tried to track that down yet, but it appears to be a computer issue.

Comment: Is there some thing common with each of the machines that is different from the machines that can access the shares okay?  Different service pack, etc.?

Comment: Not so far as I can determine.  Everyone is relatively up-to-date on Windows 7 SP1, though minor updates may differ.

Comment: Tough one.  Are they using UNC paths or mapped drives?  Is there a difference if you use one or the other?

Comment: I've tried both.  It seemed like it was an issue with mapped drives, as it appeared to go away for a little bit when I un-mapped them and had them use direct paths, but has recurred since.

Comment: Odd.  Are you mapping them via GPO or manually?  If you are mapping via GPO are you using Replace?

Comment: Via login script, actually.  It removes and re-adds them every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a computer. User could only see the files If he browsed to the share using the FQDN. I fixed the problem by disabling IPv6 under the network settings on that computer - answer found here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/334559-user-can-t-see-files-on-network-share

Comment: I have a feeling your answer could lead somewhere but it would be much more useful to clarify what the actual issue is with the problematic IPv6 configuration on that client, rather than just disabling it.